# Split a String array after X number of comma

Tags: arrays, regex, string, split

I have a String that has *n* number of values separated by commas. It looks something like this -

```
"0,3,03123132,\"2,59\",2015,132213131,\"This, is a message\",
2015,223123123,\"This, is a message number 2\",2015"
```

up to *n* number of values.

I have used the following to split the values based on comma, but not split the values with comma inside double quotes.

```
str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
```

It returns something like this -

```
[0,3,03123132,"2,59",2015,132213131,"This, is a message",
2015,223123123,"This, is a message number 2",2015]...
```

and so on up to *n*

I would like to split this String in rows and the number of rows would be equal to the value of [1] element of the array. In the above example, it would be total of 3 rows. These rows will need to consist of a set of 3 elements starting from element [2]

So the end result would look something like this -

```
[03123132,"2,59",2015]
[132213131,"This, is a message",2015]
[223123123,"This, is a message number 2",2015]
```

up to *n* number of rows.

I did some research on how to do this, but it doesn't seem to provide a simple way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex to split the data, the `csv.reader` will do exactly what you want:

```
from csv import  reader

s = "0,3,03123132,\"2,59\",2015,132213131,\"This, is a message\",2015,223123123,\"This, is a message number 2\",2015"

print(list(reader([s])[0]))
```

Output:

```
['0', '3', '03123132', '2,59', '2015', '132213131', 'This, is a message', 
'2015', '223123123', 'This, is a message number 2', '2015']
```

To group you could `zip`, starting from index 2:

```
it = iter(list(reader([s]))[0][2:])

print(list(zip(it,it,it)))
```

Which would give you:

```
 [('03123132', '2,59', '2015'), ('132213131', 'This, is a message', '2015'), ('223123123', 'This, is a message number 2', '2015')]
```

Or using `itertools.islice` to avoid slicing and creating a new list:

```
from csv import reader

from itertools import islice

it = islice(next(reader([s])), 2, None)

print(list(zip(it, it, it)))
```

Same output:

```
[('03123132', '2,59', '2015'), ('132213131', 'This, is a message', '2015'), ('223123123', 'This, is a message number 2', '2015')]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Padraic. The list consists of eleven elements and ignoring the first two elements of the list will give you 3 rows of 3 elements each. Starting the rows from element [2]. Sorry if I was not clear enough earlier.

Comment: @callMeJava, yep, I missed that, getting late here! Anyway, all you need is the csv reader and zip

Comment: would you please recommend something similar in Java?